# Re-registering $watch after de-registering

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have ng-model on a date variable. On changing that variable, I want to make some validations and during those validations I might change the start variable itself, and to make sure I don't get infinite-watch trigger, I'm de-registering the watch before, and re-registering it when the validation finishes.

The re-registering doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
var watchStartTime = $scope.$watch('timeSelection.startTime', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue === oldValue) return;
    validateStartEndTime();
}, true);

function validateStartEndTime() {
    // De-register watch
    watchStartTime();

    // Do some stuff that might change timeSelection.startTime

    // Re-register watch
    watchStartTime();
}
```

I also tried setTimeout with 0 on the re-registering, thought it might work, but it doesn't.

the `timeSelection.startTime` changes (I know for a fact it does) but the function in $watch doesn't get called again.

What am I missing?

Comment: How about `ng-change` ? or just check if `yourForm.yourDate.$error` is not present (and show visual cues/disable any "send" functionality?)

Comment: I'm using bootstrap's datePicker and for some reason the ng-change never gets triggered, but I guess thats a separate issue.
Plus the startTime might get changed from somewhere in the controller, not only from the GUI

Comment: The function returned by `$watch` is a deregistration function only. To register again, you will have to call `$watch()` with the same arguments again.

Comment: Interesting, so I can just put the entire $watch piece in a function and just call it whenever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Nikos Paraskevopoulos `$watch` returns the deregistration fn.
I think you should do something like the following...

```
var register = function() {
    var unregister = $scope.$watch('timeSelection.startTime', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal === oldVal) {
            return;
        }

        unregister();
        validateStartEndTime();
        register();
    }, true);
};

register();
```